# "breaking the window" or "breaking of the window"

Tags: prepositions

I've come across this:

*He insisted that he had nothing to do with breaking the window.*

Is it correct? Shouldn't use the preposition "of" between "breaking" and "the window"?

Comment: Both forms are used, although "breaking the window" is more common and a bit more informal. "The breaking of the window" can also sound a bit dated. There is, to me, a subtle difference in meaning which is that "breaking the window" refers to an action while "the breaking of the window" refers to an incident.; In other words someone could legitimately claim to have had "nothing to do with breaking the window" as he had not thrown the stone or given the stone to the person who had but not be able to cliam to have "nothing to do with the breaking of the window' because he helped to cover it up.